# how to create a polygon and get it coordinates with spatial data in R

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile

I Would like to know if there is a way to set a polygon interactively in a plot  spatial data image and get It's coordinates. I know there is the locator() function, but I would like to set a circles or square and get it coordinates.

Comment: See functions drawPoly and click in raster. Use coercion with as() first to SpatialLines and then to SpatialPoints and coordinates() will get them all.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but is there an way to draw an square like a  drag and hold ?

Comment: For a square you could use, e.g. `e <- raster::drawExtent()` followed by `as(e, 'SpatialPolygons')`.

Comment: thx, i discovered that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been updated so maybe I better understand the aim now. You want to plot a region with a lot of boundaries and then click a polygon on top? With the shape file provided in the comment you can do:

```
library(spatstat)
library(sp)
library(maptools)

obj <- readShapeSpatial("mun_lin.shp")
region <- unmark(as(obj, "psp"))
x11() # Necessary when using RStudio (at least on my machine)
plot(region, main = "")
x <- clickpoly(add = TRUE, col = 2, lwd = 2) # Start locator overlayed on region
```

Then you just left click the points you need and middle/right click when you are done. The points are stored as a window (`owin`) in `x`. You can get a `list` with the x,y coordinates:

```
vertices(x)
```

Comment: I get Error: object 'y' not found, I think it's something missing, i am trying to use this ShapeFile of São Paulo city https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2dnrxohhedro5ra/AAC3TpJQcXVk_JM2X8eY9qlpa?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, I had written x where it should have been y. I have updated the answer, so I hope it works now (not at my computer so it is untested).

Comment: I have updated the answer according to a (hopefully) better understanding of the question. Out of curiosity: Could you check that this works and does what you want?

Comment: Hi, it worked for me, thanks! But do you know why it get better with x11() function, cause I used in my code and it worked better

Answer (score 0):

So I had used  `drawPoly()` from the raster library, here is the code:

```
library(spatstat)
library(raster)
#load the shapefile
plot(shape)#plot it
points(data.coords,col="green",pch=4)#add data coordenates points
polygon<- drawPoly()#draw a polygon in the window
#take it limits
xlim<-polygon@bbox[1,]
ylim<-polygon@bbox[2,]
new_points<-ppp(data.coords[,1], data.coords[,2], xlim, ylim)#take points inside the polygon

new_points<- data.frame(new_points)#convert to data.frame

plot(shape)
points(new_points ,col="red",pch=4)#plot the selected points in the shape
```